# JaCoCo Maven Plugin throws error during coverage check: Cannot find default setter in class org.jacoco.report.check.Limit

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, jacoco

**UPDATE:** the problem line is

```
 <element>CLASS</element>
```

If this line is removed, the build fails for the appropriate reason e.g., insufficient coverage. Keeping question up though because my understanding is that this is a valid tag.

So I am trying to implement a JaCoCo unit test coverage check where the Maven build would fail if the coverage is not a certain number. I followed simple examples online and added the following under build plugins in the `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/jacoco</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>com/mycompany/config/**</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>check</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <rule>
                        <limits>
                            <element>CLASS</element>
                            <limit>
                                <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                <minimum>0.90</minimum>
                            </limit>
                        </limits>
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I run `mvn test`, tests are run but the plugin does not fail the build (there is about 30% coverage in the project).

When I run `mvn install` it fails with the following message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.9:check (check) on project platform-main: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.9:check for parameter element: Cannot find default setter in class org.jacoco.report.check.Limit
```

I can generate a report successfully by replacing the check step with a report step.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `check` execution is misconfigured.

Configuration contains list of rule with element type and list of limits. So `<element>` tag belongs to `<rule>` not to `<limits>`

Use this snippet

```xml
<configuration>
    <rules>
        <rule>
            <element>CLASS</element>
            <limits>
                <limit>
                    <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                    <minimum>0.90</minimum>
                </limit>
            </limits>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure why the IDE was not complaining if this was a missplaced tag.

Comment: Every plugin (even your own maven plugin) has different configuration capabilities. Because of this impossible to define all possible restrictions of all available plugins in the world. So `<configuration>` section defined as `<xs:any...>` in pom.xml schema. An IDE just helps, but the developer *knows*. :)